# How to check if the word is Japanese or English?

Tags: java

I want to have a different process for English word and Japanese word in this method:

```
if (english) {
    // say english
} else {
    // say not english
}
```

How can I achieve this in JSP?

Answer (score 14):

Japanese characters lies within certain Unicode ranges:

- U+3040–U+309F: Hiragana
- U+30A0–U+30FF: Katakana
- U+4E00–U+9FBF: Kanji

So all you basically need to do is to check if the character's codepoint lies within the known ranges.

```
Set<UnicodeBlock> japaneseUnicodeBlocks = new HashSet<UnicodeBlock>() {{
    add(UnicodeBlock.HIRAGANA);
    add(UnicodeBlock.KATAKANA);
    add(UnicodeBlock.CJK_UNIFIED_IDEOGRAPHS);
}};

String mixed = "This is a Japanese newspaper headline: ラドクリフ、マラソン五輪代表に1万m出場にも含み";

for (char c : mixed.toCharArray()) {
    if (japaneseUnicodeBlocks.contains(UnicodeBlock.of(c))) {
        System.out.println(c + " is a Japanese character");
    } else {
        System.out.println(c + " is not a Japanese character");
    }
}
```

It's unclear when exactly you'd like to say Japanese back. When the string contains mixed Japanese and Latin (or other!) characters, or when the string contains *only* Japanese characters. The above example should at least be a good starting point.

Please note that this all is completely unrelated to JSP. [JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info) is just a web presentation technology which allows you to generate HTML/CSS/JS code dynamically. Writing Java code inside JSP files is considered a [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files).

Comment: how can make this with english if chrachter not english?

Comment: can the same be done for objective-c..? I wan't to do this for russian language... please see my question here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972055/how-to-check-if-a-char-lies-between-a-certain-unicode-range

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Japanese words use chars above 256, whereas English doesn't use them. You could test if one of the chars is `>= 256` in the word.