# How to check if a char lies between a certain unicode range...?

Tags: iphone, ios, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

I want to check if a particular char I get from the text field lies between a particular hex range of unicode character set... Like if I enter capital C then I will specify the range 41-5a.. I want to do this for russian alphabet. But cant figure it out.I can get the last char entered using..

```
unichar lastEnteredChar= [[textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string] characterAtIndex:[[textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string]  length] - 1];
```

but don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access a particular character in the `UITextField` like so:

```
unichar charAt0 = [myTextField.text characterAtIndex:0];
```

So if you want the last character:

```
NSUInteger length = [myTextField.text length];
unichar lastChar = [myTextField.text characterAtIndex:length - 1];
```

Now `lastChar` is really just an `unsigned short`, so you can compare it like so:

```
if( lastChar >= 0x041 && lastChar <= 0x05A )
{
    // do something...
}
```

Whether you want to constrain it to a hex range, or some other range, is up to you. I chose the examples you gave (41 thru 5a).